# WalletConnect fails to get bundled with vite

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

I have a vite project that uses @walletconnect/client. Everything works fine with

```
npm run dev
```

but during build (`npm run build`) I get these errors

```
error during build:
Error: 'removeHexPrefix' is not exported by node_modules/@walletconnect/encoding/dist/cjs/index.js, imported by node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/ethereum.js
```

I have tried a few vite configurations from github

1.

```
optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@walletconnect/*']
  },
```

2. optimizeDeps: {
   exclude: ['@walletconnect/*']
   },

3

```
build: {
    commonjsOptions: {exclude: ['@walletconnect*'], include: []},
  },
```

I do not know anything else to do, but if you have come across this issue or something similar. Please let me know how you solved yours.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the [same issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7257) (I highly suggest you to check it out). Fixed with this config:

````
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import nodePolyfills from "rollup-plugin-polyfill-node";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  // Node.js global to browser globalThis
  define: {
    global: "globalThis",
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte(),
    inject({
      util: "util/",
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [nodePolyfills()],
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],same issue
    },
  },
});```
````